# Is it possible to SELECT N first rows from database using ROWNUM if some rows have the same value?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, rownum

I'm trying to select N first rows from a database using ROWNUM. The problem is that if I want to select 6 first values of age with names of people with this age and some of the have the same value of age not every person will be shown.
For example

```
name       age
Peter       15
Mark        22
Kelly       17
Mike        17
George      17
```

If I want to show people with 2 biggest values of age ROWNUM will show Mark and Kelly or Mike or George. Not all three of them. The expected result is:

```
Name        age
Mark         22
Kelly        17
Mike         17
George       17
```

Is it possible to get this result using ROWNUM? Not RANK, DENSE_RANK, JOIN, correlated subquery but ROWNUM?

Comment: This is exactly what `dense_rank()` is for. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Because I was asked to do it on my exam today, and I wasn't able to deal with it and I still don't have idea, how to do it using ROWNUM. I know all other ways I wrote in opening post, but ROWNUM? No idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution `dense_rank()`, but you can do it with just `row_number()` and some subqueries:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.age in (select age
                from (select age
                      from t t2
                      order by age desc
                     ) x
                where rownum <= 2
               );
```

In Oracle 12+, you can simplify this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.age in (select age
                from t t2
                order by age desc
                fetch first 2 rows only
               );
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first solution use logic that satisfy me. You have only 1 mistake. It should've been WHERE ROWNUM < 3. WHERE ROWNUM=2 will return exactly 0 results in every query it will be used in because that's how databases works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
select *
from test
where age in (
                select age
                from ( 
                        select age
                        from test
                        group by age
                        order by age desc
                      )
                where rownum <=2
              )
```